# Devise and ActiveAdmin - Edit User - undefined method user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I just installed ActiveAdmin to manage my users using

```
rails generate active_admin:install --skip-users
rails generate active_admin:resource User
```

in order to use my existing User model I use with Devise.

My config in the initializer active_admin.rb is:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
  config.current_user_method   = :current_user
  config.logout_link_path      = :destroy_user_session_path
  config.logout_link_method    = :delete
  config.allow_comments        = false
  config.batch_actions         = true
end
```

The authentication method is in my application_controller.rb:

```
def authenticate_admin_user!
  redirect_to new_user_session_path unless current_user.try(:is_admin?) 
end
```

and in routes.rb I have:

```
devise_for :users
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

I can access the index but it breaks when I want to edit a user or create a new one.
Here is the bstacktrace:

```
Started GET "/admin/users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-26 14:45:38 +0800
  Processing by Admin::UsersController#new as HTML
    User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 20 LIMIT 1
    User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
    Rendered /home/flashgordon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb (426.2ms)
  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 440ms

  ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user_id' for #<User:0x007ff5f522fdb0>):
      1: insert_tag renderer_for(:new)
    activemodel (3.2.13) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
    activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1152:in `value'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1143:in `value'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:580:in `to_select_tag'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:157:in `select'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:642:in `select'
    /home/flashgordon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/formtastic-2.2.1/lib/formtastic/inputs/select_input.rb:154:in `select_html'
    /home/flashgordon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/formtastic-2.2.1/lib/formtastic/inputs/select_input.rb:149:in `block in to_html'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:40:in `block in capture'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:187:in `with_output_buffer'
    haml (4.0.2) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_xss_mods.rb:5:in `with_output_buffer_with_haml_xss'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:40:in `capture'
    haml (4.0.2) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:59:in `capture_with_haml'
    /home/flashgordon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/formtastic-2.2.1/lib/formtastic/inputs/base/wrapping.rb:11:in `input_wrapping'
    /home/flashgordon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/formtastic-2.2.1/lib/formtastic/inputs/select_input.rb:146:in `to_html'
    formtastic (2.2.1) lib/formtastic/helpers/input_helper.rb:240:in `input'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:19:in `block in input'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:166:in `with_new_form_buffer'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:19:in `input'
    formtastic (2.2.1) lib/formtastic/helpers/inputs_helper.rb:329:in `block in fieldset_contents_from_column_list'
    formtastic (2.2.1) lib/formtastic/helpers/inputs_helper.rb:317:in `collect'
    formtastic (2.2.1) lib/formtastic/helpers/inputs_helper.rb:317:in `fieldset_contents_from_column_list'
    formtastic (2.2.1) lib/formtastic/helpers/inputs_helper.rb:296:in `inputs'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:13:in `block in inputs'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:166:in `with_new_form_buffer'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:13:in `inputs'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/form.rb:43:in `block in default_form_config'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/form.rb:23:in `instance_exec'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/form.rb:23:in `block in main_content'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:40:in `block in capture'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:187:in `with_output_buffer'
    haml (4.0.2) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_xss_mods.rb:5:in `with_output_buffer_with_haml_xss'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:40:in `capture'
    haml (4.0.2) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:59:in `capture_with_haml'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:378:in `form_for'
    haml (4.0.2) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:146:in `form_for_with_haml'
    haml (4.0.2) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_xss_mods.rb:28:in `form_for_with_haml_xss'
    /home/flashgordon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/formtastic-2.2.1/lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:161:in `block in semantic_form_for'
    /home/flashgordon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/formtastic-2.2.1/lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:192:in `with_custom_field_error_proc'
    /home/flashgordon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/formtastic-2.2.1/lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:160:in `semantic_form_for'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/view_helpers/form_helper.rb:8:in `active_admin_form_for'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element.rb:175:in `method_missing'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/form.rb:22:in `main_content'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in build_main_content_wrapper'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:18:in `div'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:77:in `block in build_main_content_wrapper'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:18:in `div'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:76:in `build_main_content_wrapper'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:60:in `block in build_page_content'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:18:in `div'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:59:in `build_page_content'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:42:in `block (2 levels) in build_page'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:18:in `div'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:39:in `block in build_page'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:38:in `build_page'
    activeadmin (0.6.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:10:in `build'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
    /home/flashgordon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb:1:in `block in __home_flashgordon__rvm_gems_ruby_______p____gems_activeadmin_______app_views_active_admin_resource_new_html_arb__4493823286655400845_61452940'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `instance_eval'
    arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `initialize'
    /home/flashgordon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb:1:in `new'
    /home/flashgordon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb:1:in `__home_flashgordon__rvm_gems_ruby_______p____gems_activeadmin_______app_views_active_admin_resource_new_html_arb__4493823286655400845_61452940'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
    /home/flashgordon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    sunspot_rails (1.3.3) lib/sunspot/rails/railties/controller_runtime.rb:15:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
    /home/flashgordon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in new'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:230:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:230:in `default_render'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:160:in `to_html'
    responders (0.9.3) lib/responders/flash_responder.rb:104:in `to_html'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:153:in `respond'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:146:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:239:in `respond_with'
    /home/flashgordon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/inherited_resources-1.4.0/lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:19:in `new'
    /home/flashgordon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:32:in `new'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:480:in `_run__2693105796829942473__process_action__3316774578101385478__callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
    activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
    journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
    journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
    journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
    warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
    warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
    warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
    activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
    activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2837449993009062074__call__316444418893315790__callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
    railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
    railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
    railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
    activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
    railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
    railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
    rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
    railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
    puma (1.6.3) lib/puma/server.rb:412:in `handle_request'
    puma (1.6.3) lib/puma/server.rb:306:in `process_client'
    puma (1.6.3) lib/puma/server.rb:215:in `block in run'
    puma (1.6.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:94:in `call'
    puma (1.6.3) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:94:in `block in spawn_thread'


    Rendered /home/flashgordon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.9ms)
    Rendered /home/flashgordon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.7ms)
    Rendered /home/flashgordon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (20.2ms)
```

Any help would be awesome :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the stack trace...

Comment: post updated with stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an issue on github, the author of the gem found the problem.

In my User model I had an old unused relationship where a user belongs_to a user.

I removed it and it is working fine now.